# Fastest Way Of Sending an Image via HTTP POST

Tags: java, image, http, post

I'm creating a Java application that takes a screenshot and sends it to a web server via a HTTP POST request. I'm currently at the part of sending the screenshot to the webserver and I am unsure of the best approach. I've thought of three options in my head so far, but I am unsure which is the fastest/most preferred one to do:

1. Send bytes of the image and "re-create" it on the web server side.
2. Just send the image normally to the web server.
3. Send the image normally to the webserver but in a gzip.

Any help leading me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "normally" or "bytes of the image" ? What file format is the image in? Why don't you just send the image as the png or jpeg or gif that you have saved it as?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it's a png, I did have sending it normally in the 3 options above but I also want a fast solution, and I feel like there's better, faster, ways of doing this (which is why I'm asking).

Comment: There is no difference between (1) and (2).

Answer (score 0):

Most image formats are already encoded thus encoding them to gzip won't make much difference. 
Just send the image the way you do, no need for any conversion.